# is there asp.net core websocket clients available in unity?

Tags: asp.net-core, unity-game-engine, websocket, asp.net-core-signalr

Can signal handle 30 calls per seconds for each user? Js and node.js is a little hard to get used to and I am looking for a .net solution.

I tried node.js and it was not so good when hosting on digital ocean.

Comment: Do you have any concern about this issue ? If you need further help, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**  Can signal handle 30 calls per seconds for each user? 
**Answer:**     Yes

---

**Steps 1**

Create a asp.net core signalr web server.

[Create the hub in your web application.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

**Steps 2**

Create signalr client to connect the signalr hub in web server.

For more details, please check the blog: [[Unity] Communicate with SignalR from Unity](https://dev.to/masanori_msl/unity-communicate-with-signalr-from-unity-3739)

Comment: I think there must be some websocket without using signalR

Comment: @NWAsaba If you want to use signalr in unity3d, then you can use the link I provided, and if you have doubts, you can describe your application scenario.

Comment: @NWAsaba I think you are right to consider using signalr, because azure provides signalr service, which guarantees reliability and scalability, ensures the stable operation of the service, and can better cope with the large increase in the number of users in the future .

Comment: I hope some official signalr client exists,not sure if the recommended one supports android and ios,but thanks for the info regarding azure.